# Power supply to a sensor to be mounted on a shaft rotating at >1000 RPM

Tags: power, rotary, slip-ring

My project involves mounting an ultrasonic transducer on a shaft rotating at >1000 RPM. What possibilities exist to supply power to the transducer?

I cannot use slip rings because slip rings need to be permanently fixed on the shaft and in this case, the shaft needs to be taken out of the assembly on a regular basis. I would be really grateful if you could give me some suggestions. The accessible area of the shaft is around 10-15 cm.

Comment: It would help if you could give us some more details, such 1) what your power requirements for the shaft mounted transducer are an 2) what it is your trying to measure?

Comment: slip rings that don't need to be peramnanently fixed to the shaft? It's only 1000 rpm after all. What power is required? Rotary transformer? Optical? Geared generator? Open skeleton alternator consisting of a coil of wire on the shaft, and a fixed permanent magnet close by?

Comment: Mount a couple of coils on the shaft and fix magnets close to the shaft. Need a dc to dc converter probably... like an eddy current generator...

Comment: How much power? Fixed magnet and rotating coils is one way. Big LED and small solar cells would be another.

Comment: why does it have to be on the shaft? what are you trying to measure?  IF it has to go onto the shaft, as others stated... rotary transformer, this is essentially what a wound rotor SR does with "rotating diodes" on the rotor

Comment: Ydlidar chose to power the rotating piece with an inductor and transmit data with an LED a link I found https://simple-duino.com/a-la-decouverte-du-ydlidar-x4/

Comment: The transducer requires around 150 V DC power in the form of short pulses ( ~500 ns) , to be transmitted at about 1 MHz frequency...so that waves travel through the shaft and can be picked up by receiving transducers along its length.. I need to measure the change in material along the length of the shaft

Comment: How much power does this transducer require? Have you considered just strapping a battery onto the shaft along with the transducer? And since "the shaft needs to be taken out of the assembly on a regular basis", this also gives the opportunity to replace the battery on a regular basis if necessary...

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call a square wave "short pulses".

Comment: If you can't attach slip rings to the shaft what can you attach to the shaft?

Comment: Wireless power transfert? But can it work on a rotating shaft? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a rotary transformer. You'd need two channels: one for your power supply, and one for your return signal.

Answer (score 0):

One assumes you already have a mount for your sensor on the shaft, and if the shaft is removable, that the mount must be splined or keyed to the shaft?

In that case, have the slip rings on a bush which is a sliding fit on the shaft, and either attach the bush to the sensor mount (both mechanically and electrically), or have a similar key/spline to the shaft and just an electrical connection to the sensor.